# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 in Xcode

Tags: xcode, linker, frameworks, static-libraries, linker-errors

I have a framework Xcode project A, and an app Xcode project B that uses the framework binary of A.

When I try to instantiate an object of my framework in my app, it gives me this link error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyClass", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

My framework is `arm64`, I verified with `lipo -info` .

The symbol `_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyClass` is in the framework, I verified with `nm mylib | grep MyClass`

I don't understand how it is possible that this symbol is not found.

What could be the cause of this ? Any help would be appreciated, thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by setting `Symbols Hidden by Default` to `No` in the build settings.

Or, I could also add `__attribute__ ((visibility("default")))` in front of my class if I wanted to keep that option and hide all other symbols.